# A question about Markov Chain.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

> > Suppose $\{X_n\}$ has Markov property. Show that for any $n,r \in \Bbb N,i \in S,A \subset S^n, B \subset S^r$
> >
> > $P[(X_{n+1}, \cdots , X_{n+r}) \in B\ \mid X_n=i,(X_0,\cdots,X_{n-1}) \in A]=P[(X_{n+1},\cdots,X_{n+r}) \in B\ \mid X_n=i]$.
> >
> > If further $C \subset S$ then,
> >
> > $P[(X_{n+1}, \cdots , X_{n+r}) \in B\ \mid X_n \in C,(X_0,\cdots,X_{n-1}) \in A]=P[(X_{n+1},\cdots,X_{n+r}) \in B\ \mid X_n \in C]$.

How do I proceed using Markov property? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems there is a counterexample to the second statement given [here (see the answer with 103 upvotes)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics).